# Concurrent lines simply

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is the equation of a beam of concurrent lines simply not, $k(ax + by + c) = 0$?

I think the line is the same if multiplying by a constant

Comment: I don't know but you will at least need $k \ne 0$

Comment: Ok I've done a little more research here.  every time I see "concurrent lines" it appears to mean they all go through a particular point, not that they all coincide completely.  What's your context?  What's the equation they give you?

Comment: This question is sadly missing context: you essentially copied and pasted and assigned problem.  Then you assign it to us.  That's not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the line is the same, so you don't get a beam.

Instead, take any two distinct lines containing the common point and form a linear combination:

$$\lambda(a'x+b'y+c')+\mu(a''x+b''y+c'')=0.$$

Comment: Yves, is the word "beam"  what would usually be expressed as "pencil" in mathematical English?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(mathematics)

Comment: @WillJagy: that's how I understood it here. In other contexts, a beam can be a line with a width, or a pencil of concurrent lines but with a limited angular range.

Comment: Thanks, Yves...